# How to get sum of distinct values in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

Example, I have the below column where I need to add only the unique values.

```
number
44
44
55
55
66
66
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this fairly simply with a measure.

```
Distinct Sum = SUMX(DISTINCT(Table1[number]), Table1[number])
```

The `DISTINCT` function creates a list of distinct values in the specified column. Then `SUMX` goes through this list one at a time and adds `Table1[number]` for each row.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean that you'd like the sum of `44+55+66=165`.
To me it seems that the best approach is to build a new table using the measure `unique = DISTINCT(Table1[number])`. You *could* add it as a measeure in an existing table, but it will most likely cause troubles in your visualizations.

So if you have a table like this:

[image]

Then you can go to the `Report` tab and select `Modeling > New Table` and insert the formula above.

And then you can easily display the total in a `Table` or `Matrix visualization` like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply...this is present by Analyst & duration so how can I define the same by analyst & the sum of distinct number?
1 44
1 44
1 55
1 55
1 66
1 66
2 22
2 11
2 22
2 11
2 44
2 44

Comment: @AbhirupDash No problem! Analyst and duration? Your question was limited to one column. Now you're adding new details and information that turns the issue into a completely different question. So if you don't mind I would suggest that you write it as a follow-up question. At least that's what I usually do to keep the questions and answers focused and to the point.